# In a 2d array. Iterate for the first 2 rows and 2 columns, then first 2 rows again, next 2 columns etc

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, iteration

I am trying to iterate over an array in a weird way. I can't think of a good way to do it. I need iterate over the first 2 rows for just 2 columns at a time. So 4 index positions at a time. I would continue on the 1st 2 rows until out of columns then continue to the next 2 rows. I would do this until I was out of rows. I can assume the array will always be an even number of rows and columns (2, 4 , 6) , but not that they are square. It can end up being 4x6 etc. Also the smallest array possible will be a 4x4.

Any suggestions? I am drawing a blank besides just hard coding it of sorts. Find the length of a row, divide it by 2, then just iterate that many times?

Example: I have a 2d array. It is 4X4. That is 4, four element square 'blocks". Blocks are 2x2. So the first block I need to manipulate first is at index positions [0][0],[0][1],[1][0],[1][1].

Comment: Your question just went over my head. Couldn't get hold of it.

Comment: Your description seems too complicated. Don't think someone will give you proper answer, please post code example what you did so far

Comment: I will put an example in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Iterate rows  r = 0;(r +1) < r_max; r+=2  
   Iterate colums c = 0; (c+1) < c_max; c +=2  
      operate on r, r+1 and c,c+1
```

If you feel the "2" is hardcoding, you can easily paramerize it, but the "operate" stage might need 2 more loops for that depending on what you want to do. Otherwise this is quite fine.

I would just add checks or asserts on the top which verify what you say are your assumptions

Comment: Wouldn't this give me just the first 'block' then I would have to do another nested for loop for the next set.

Comment: @Keystone1722 in the operate section you would operate on your 4 elements, the 2 "iterate"s are your loops which get you each block

Comment: this got me thinking of another, really simple way to do it. for (int i = 0; i < Map.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < Map[0].length; j++) then in the operate column I just ask for the i/2 and the j/2 of the smaller array. It gives me the correct index position for that 'block'

Comment: @Keystone1722 Am not sure I got your comment there, but glad I could help